# Idiomatic form of dealing with un-initialized var

Tags: scala

I'm coding up my first Scala script to get a feel for the language, and I'm a bit stuck as to the best way to achieve something.

My situation is the following, I have a method which I need to call N times, this method returns an Int on each run (might be different, there's a random component to the execution), and I want to keep the best run (the smallest value returned on these runs).

Now, coming from a Java/Python background, I would simply initialize the variable with null/None, and compare in the if, something like:

```
best = None
for...
    result = executionOfThings()
    if(best is None or result < best):
        best = result
```

And that's that (pardon for the semi-python pseudo-code).

Now, on Scala, I'm struggling a bit. I've read about the usage of Option and pattern matching to achieve the same effect, and I guess I could code up something like (this was the best I could come up with):

```
best match {
    case None => best = Some(res)
    case Some(x) if x > res => best = Some(res)
    case _ =>
  }
```

I believe this works, but I'm not sure if it's the most idiomatic way of writing it. It's clear enough, but a bit verbose for such a simple "use-case".

Anyone that could shine a functional light on me?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to do with `best` afterwards? This looks like this assignment could be avoided. You could probably also exploit the monadic properties of `Option` to make this a bit more concise.

Comment: Return it/print it out. best is basically the result of the algorithm.

Comment: You can just use the `match` as an expression then, instead of assigning it to something.

Comment: Use the match as an expression? Like I said, my first Scala script ;) Could you elaborate?

Comment: Yeah, I don't no Scala very well, but I'll see whether I can turn this into a proper answer.

Comment: best = best match {case None => Some(best) ...}

Comment: What about something like `results.min`?

Comment: Appending results to a list and returning the min? It's a possible workaround for this case, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this *particular* problem, not in general, I would suggest initializing with `Int.MaxValue` as long as you're guaranteed that `N >= 1`.  Then you just

```
if (result < best) best = result
```

You could also, with `best` as an option,

```
best = best.filter(_ >= result).orElse( Some(result) )
```

if the optionality is important (e.g. it is possible that `N == 0`, and you don't take a distinct path through the code in that case).  This is a more general way to deal with optional values that may get replaced: use `filter` to keep the non-replaced cases, and `orElse` to fill in the replacement if needed.

Comment: This seems like the best alternative I've seen. Thank you for the explanation on the usage of filter with Option.

Answer (score 1):

edit: adjusted to @user-unknown's suggestion

I would suggest you to rethink you whole computation to be more functional. You mutate state which should be avoided. I could think of a recursive version of your code:

```
def calcBest[A](xs: List[A])(f: A => Int): Int = {
  def calcBest(xs: List[A], best: Int = Int.MaxValue): Int = xs match {
    // will match an empty list
    case Nil => best
    // x will hold the head of the list and rest the rest ;-)
    case x :: rest => calcBest(rest, math.min(f(x), best))
  }
  calcBest(xs)
}
```

callable with `calcBest(List(7,5,3,8,2))(_*2) // => res0: Int = 4`

With this you have no mutable state at all.

Another way would be to use foldLeft on the list:

```
list.foldLeft(Int.MaxValue) { case (best,x) => math.min(calculation(x),best) }
```

`foldLeft` takes a B and a PartialFunction of `Tuple2[B,A] => B` and returns B

Both ways are equivalent. The first one is probably faster, the second is more readable. Both traverse a list call a function on each value and return the smallest. Which from your snippet is what you want, right?

Comment: If you could pass the 'calculation' function into the method. Maybe, a function Any=>Int or A=>Int: `def calcBest [A] (xs: List[A], f: (A => Int)): Int = {`

Comment: Yes, the more general, the better. I just wanted to give a quick example ;-). But I will adjust it.

Comment: Thank you for the more functional example! My case doesn't exactly involve applying a function to each element on a list, the call is exactly the same, with exactly the same argument, the results will differ due to randomization inside the function, but I think I can adapt, and your example will certainly come in handy.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the min function:

```
(for (... executionOfThings()).min
```

Example:

```
((1 to 5).map (x => 4 * x * x - (x * x * x))).min
```

Comment: Which would iterate over the first list, build a new one and iterate over that as well. It would work, but is not very performant.

Comment: @drexin: I don't understand which 2 lists you're talking about. Would sound like premature optimization to me, if it would deal with a real problem.

Comment: collections or whatever... the thing is, that it will traverse all values 2 times. This is not critical when you have only small amounts of values. If you can guarantee that it's okay. But avoiding the second traversal is not hard.

Comment: @drexin: The question was about an idiomatic way to get the minimum. Not about a premature performance optimization. Without further knowledge about the function being called, I wouldn't speculate about the performance. Readability, maintainability, understandable code is almost always more important.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would offer another idiomatic solution. You can use `Iterator.continually` to create an infinite-length iterator that's lazily evaluated, `take(N)` to limit the iterator to N elements, and use `min` to find the winner.

```
Iterator.continually { executionOfThings() }.take(N).min
```